# drop down from project list

Tags: jquery, css, html, drop-down-menu

I am working on a multi-toggle drop down menu, and the functionality seems to be working properly, but there is a slight styling issue that is bothersome...I am having trouble removing a small white gap between the dropdown image that will toggle to list items. I want to remove the small white padding between dropdown menu item and the images below the toggled image...hopefully that makes sense...below is the html, css, and js.

THanks in advance for any help!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <title>Dan Meier/ Designer</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Portfolio of Dan Meier">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Freelance, Design, Illustration, Graphics, Website Design, UI, User Interface, Digital Design">
    <meta name="author" content="Dan Meier">

    <!-- Stylesheets -->
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style>
ul, menu, dir {
display: block;
list-style-type: disc;
-webkit-margin-before: 0em;
-webkit-margin-after: 0em;
-webkit-margin-start: 0px;
-webkit-margin-end: 0px;
-webkit-padding-start: 40px;

}

.dropdown a {
  text-decoration: none;

}

.dropdown [data-toggle="dropdown"] {
  position: relative;
  display: block;

}

.dropdown [data-toggle="dropdown"]:hover {
  background: #ffffff;
}

<!-- All Projects -->
        <div id="projects_container_new">
        <div id="all_projects">
            <div class="col1">

            <ul>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"><img class="thumb_image" src="images/UX-UI-Dev_cover.jpg"><i class="icon-arrow"></i></a>

                 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <div class="thumb" data-url="project_thesis.html" data-num="0">
                    <div class="thumb_title"><span class="thumb_client">Published Thesis Work</span><br />Algorithm & Parametric Design</div>
                    <div class="thumb_hover"><div class="view_project">See<br />Work</div></div>
                    <img class="thumb_image" src="images/thesis_cover.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="thumb" data-url="project_conceptualthinking.html" data-num="3">
                    <div class="thumb_title"><span class="thumb_client">Conceptual Thinking</span><br />Visual Design</div>
                    <div class="thumb_hover"><div class="view_project">See<br />Work</div></div>
                    <img class="thumb_image" src="images/design_cover.jpg">
                </div>
                </ul>
                </li>
                <div class="thumb" data-url="project_thesis.html" data-num="0">
                    <div class="thumb_title"><span class="thumb_client">Published Thesis Work</span><br />Algorithm & Parametric Design</div>
                    <div class="thumb_hover"><div class="view_project">See<br />Work</div></div>
                    <img class="thumb_image" src="images/thesis_cover.jpg">
                </div>
             </ul>

<!-- scripts -->
<script>// Dropdown Menu
var dropdown = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown');
var dropdownArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(dropdown,0);
dropdownArray.forEach(function(el){
    var button = el.querySelector('a[data-toggle="dropdown"]'),
            menu = el.querySelector('.dropdown-menu'),
            arrow = button.querySelector('i.icon-arrow');

    button.onclick = function(event) {
        if(!menu.hasClass('show')) {
            menu.classList.add('show');
            menu.classList.remove('hide');
            arrow.classList.add('open');
            arrow.classList.remove('close');
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        else {
            menu.classList.remove('show');
            menu.classList.add('hide');
            arrow.classList.remove('open');
            arrow.classList.add('close');
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    };
})

Element.prototype.hasClass = function(className) {
    return this.className && new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + className + "(\\s|$)").test(this.className);
};//@ sourceURL=pen.js
</script>
<script src="/assets/common/localstorage.js"></script><script src="/assets/post/scroll/remember_scroll.js"></script><script>RememberScroll.init();</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Styles CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #ffffff;
    font-family: "adelle-sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 22px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

/* -------- Projects --------- */

#projects_container_new {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 95%;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

#all_projects {
    z-index: 999;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: -2% auto 0 auto;
    padding: 0 40px 120px 40px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#all_projects .col1 {
    z-index: 999;
    float: left;
    width: 90%;
    height:auto;
    background-color: ;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

#all_projects .col2 {
    z-index: 999;
    float: left;
    width: 90%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

#all_projects .col3 {
    z-index: 999;
    float: left;
        width: 90%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

#all_projects .col1b {
    z-index: 999;
    float: left;
        width: 90%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    position: relative;
    display: none;
}

#all_projects .col2b {
        display: none;
        z-index: 999;
    float: left;
     width: 50%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    position: relative;
    display: none;
}

#all_projects .col1c {
    z-index: 999;
    float: left;
        width: 90%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    position: relative;
    display: none;
}

#all_projects .thumb {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#all_projects .thumb .thumb_title {
    z-index: 999;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 0 6% 5%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
}

#all_projects .thumb .thumb_client {
    z-index: 999;
    font-size: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#all_projects .thumb .thumb_image {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

#all_projects .thumb .thumb_hover {
    z-index: 998;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    right: 15px;
    bottom: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    background-image: url("../images/hoverdark.png");
    opacity: 0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
    -webkit-transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#all_projects .thumb .view_project {
    z-index: 999;
    position: absolute;
    width: 120px;
    height: 60px;
    top: 70%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -30px 0 0 -60px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "adelle-sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 17px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #000000;
    background-image: url("../images/hover-icon.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center bottom;
    opacity: 0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

Comment: what is in style.css?

Comment: create a fiddle. I tried to create a fiddle from your example and see the result. http://jsfiddle.net/KV8y2/

Comment: sorry, i just added the additional related styles CSS, thanks.